# How to get thi value

Tags: php

How to get `3508` and `31472` from this:

```
$info = {"ioc":true,"sid":3702088,"ci":3508,"cp":{"id":93006,"t":102,"s":true},"pr":25000,"whid":31472}
```

I use `json_decode`, but the result is:

> "Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to
> string..."

Comment: It's a json string. You can decode it, and then access it by key.

Comment: Please, edit the question and include the code, that generates this error.

Comment: That's not even valid PHP

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach it like so:

```php
$info = '{"ioc":true,"sid":3702088,"ci":3508,"cp":{"id":93006,"t":102,"s":true},"pr":25000,"whid":31472}';

$dec = json_decode($info, true); // true converts to an associative PHP array

echo "ci: " . $dec["ci"] . "<br>";
echo "whid: " . $dec["whid"];
```

**Output:**

```
ci: 3508
whid: 31472
```